# How do I filter max value of two list in Erlang using comprehensions?

Tags: erlang, list-comprehension

I want to have a list made from two list `X` and `Y` where you only take the `X` value if the `X` value is bigger than value from `Y`. I tried this:

`[ X || X <- [1,2,3], Y <- [0,2,1], X > Y].`

but it doesn't work like I thought. I want output: `[1,3]` but I got:

`[1,2,2,3,3,3]`

How I do I do this using list comprehensions ?

Comment: Did you mean the output should be `[1, 3]`?

Comment: Yeah. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `lists:zip` and list comprehension:

```
1> [X || {X, Y} <- lists:zip([1, 2, 3], [0, 2, 1]), X > Y].
[1,3]
```